# Cloudera Data Science Workbench Access Shared Drive on Windows Server

Tags: python, cloudera, mount, shared

I am using Cloudera Data Science Workbench (CDSW) with Python. I am trying to access a shared drive hosted on Windows Server.
The script reads files from the shared driver, processes and saves the out put in a same folder.

The official document at https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/data-science-workbench/1-6-x/topics/cdsw_using_git.html doesn't have an option to do that.

I was wondering if that's possible and if yes, please advise.
I tired using the code below for one of the files

```
import os

path = os.path.join('server_name', 'folder', 'file.txt')

with open(path) as f:
  data = f.readline()
```

But, keep getting this error

```
  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'server_name/folder/file.txt'
```

Eventually I would like to go through the `folder` and iterate through all files and save the output to `folder/output`.

Comment: Did you ever find this out? I can not locate the answer anywhere.